# Connection to iPhone via cable. How is it done?

Tags: iphone

Quick question, but will probably have a long answer.
Let's say I plug in my iPhone to my PC computer (or Mac, if it's simpler. I've got both) - how would I get access to the files from my app?

I'm talking about having it like a drive; I can tell my app to look, for example, in

```
/Volumes/iPhone/ {and the local path on the device goes here}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at iPhone Explorer http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/ and Phone Disk http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/ . Still it might not serve your needs to access files via a mount point directly (without those tools)